# Бинарные деревья поиска. Помогите пожалуйста с алгоритмом решения

Tags: java, дерево, binary

В бинарном дереве поиска найти максимальное поддерево с наибольшим числом вершин, в котором для каждой нелистьевой вершины  число вершин в левом поддереве больше числа вершин в правом поддереве.

Comment: Начните с выбора подходящего обхода дерева

Comment: @MBo выбрал. обратный обход

Comment: Все верно. Как результат обхода, получайте размеры поддеревьев, при l>r обновляйте максимум, если он меньше l+r+1, и передавайте этот размер вверх

Comment: @MBo а как сделать, чтобы поддерево, не подходящее балансировке не выбиралось?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Выполняем обратный обход, при котором поддеревья посещаются раньше их общего корня.

После получения размеров деревьев сравниваем их, и если левое больше правого, и оба значения неотрицательные, то сумму размеров сравниваем с текущим максимумом размера, и  передаём на уровень выше.

Иначе передаём выше значение -1, что означает, что деревья в этой ветви "плохие".

Примерно так:

```
int Walk(Root)
   if (Root==Null)
       return 0 
   lsize = Walk(Root.left)
   rsize = Walk(Root.right)
   if (lsize==0 && rsize ==0)
        return 1
   if (lsize<0 || rsize<0 || lsize<=rsize)
        return -1
   size = lsize + rsize + 1
   maxsize = max(maxsize, size)
   return size
```